# Why is called n-type and p-type semiconductor? What is behind the choice of n and p as letters to represent the 2 different types of semiconductors?

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors

This is a naming question, not so much about electrical engineering.

I keep forgetting/mixing up which is the `n-type` and which is the `p-type` semiconductor.

Usually the names act like mnemonic devices for us to more easily recall which object is associated with which label/word.

**What does the `n` stand for?**

**What does the `p` stand for?**

For example, I would name it `h-type` form `hole-type` instead of p-type to remove the confusion. But I'm assuming there is already a connection like this behind the use of p and n letters - i just don't know it.

Are this just arbitrary names/letters? (doesn't make much sense to be arbitrary)

What keeps you personally from mixing the 2.

Comment: negative/positive.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. oh crap,  this must be the dumbest question ever :))

Comment: For bipolar transistors, NPN = Not Pointing iN (the arrow on the emitter points away from the base, out of the symbol), PNP = Pointing iN (arrow points towards the base, into the symbol)

Comment: Nah, just an honest question with an easy answer! I've always been fond of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/104617/38335), and am glad the user didn't remove it :)

Comment: PNP = pointing in proudly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The n stands for negatively doped, when you add more electrons to a semiconductor.
The p stands for positively doped, when you add less electrons or holes.

I know that electrons are negative, and holes are positive, that's how I remember.